# xCode, Swift 3.0 JSON parse string response

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to get the status code and put it in an if statement. This code will run in the Xcode playground.

Right now status returns as **["200"]** with square brackets around it. If I remove the brackets it returns as **nil**.

How do I return status as **200** and put it in an if statement?

```
import Foundation

let str = "{\"names\": [\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"],\"status\":[\"200\"],\"message\":\"User has been  created\",\"id\":null,\"username\":\"asdf\"}"//"{\"names\": [\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"]}"
let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
    let status = json["status"] as? [String]

} catch let error as NSError {
     print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a "**:**" after `\"status\"`

```
let str = "{\"names\": [\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"],\"status\":[\"200\"],\"message\":\"User has been  created\",\"id\":null,\"username\":\"asdf\"}"//"{\"names\": [\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"]}"
```

**EDIT : see comment of OP below**

It returns **["status"]** and that's perfectly normal because your `json` object is an `Array` of `String` ( `[String]` ). To get `200` you have to fetch the first object of this array :

```
if let array = json["status"] as? [String]
{
   let code = array.first // Here, code should be 200
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that was a typo when I was writing the question. My code has the colon so I still get the response ["200"]